# What's the name of the song that is played at exactly 3:38 of Hunter X Hunter episode 123?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

At exactly 3:38 of *Hunter X Hunter* episode 123, there's a bell-like chords and it just sounds so amazing. It is quite short and is only a few seconds but I'm hoping that section is apart of a whole song.

If it is, what's the name of the song?

Answer (score -2):

This is *Invaders* from *"Hunter X Hunter The Last Mission (Theatrical Anime)" Original Soundtrack* ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LgCF07nHwc))